# Increasing or decreasing offset using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup window. I want to have two buttons plus and minus over the popup. the two buttons on click should be capable to change the offset of the popup window. my question may be immature but i am newbie in jquery so i cant handle the scenario. how to enable the buttons to work.

```
 <div class="button" id="show">
    <button type="button">Show popup</button>
</div>


<div class="container-popup" id="container-popup">
<div>
    <button type="button" id="plus">Increase</button>
    <button type="button" id="minus">Decrease</button>
</div>
    <div class="pop-up" id="pop-up">
        <div class="circleBase type2" id="close">x</div>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L6g6Q/):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#plus").click(function(){
        var x=$("#pop-up").offset();
        $("#pop-up").offset({top : x.top + 5, left : x.left + 5});      
});
```

Set offset for the popup element. Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6g6Q/2/)